# Error: Attempt to use a dehydrated detector: CMComponent_1 -> ngModelChange

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, wijmo5

I'm using checkbox on wijmo grid header, to select all below rows

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="_chkSelectAll" (change)="SelectAll()" id="chkSelectAll"/>
```

and using following ts code

```
 SelectAll(): void {     
        var chk = document.getElementById('chkSelectAll') as HTMLInputElement;
        var chkSelect = chk.checked;

        this._chkSelectAll = chkSelect;
    }
```

but getting error

```
Error: Attempt to use a dehydrated detector: CMComponent_1 -> ngModelChange
```

I also used setTimeout() in SelectAll() function  but it doesn't work for me.

The same code is working on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IVBuVegpAEknwSAknXHy?p=preview)

Comment: The plunker you have provided is using old version of angular release. Can you provide plunker with latest release with error you are getting ?

Comment: I'm using the same version of angular as in plunker